# forEach & Promise.all() doesn't works

Tags: adonis.js

I have a problem with *forEach Promise*... It doesn't works on **AdonisJS**.

```
await Promise.all(items.map(async (item) => {
    console.log(item)
}))
```

No console logged...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would bet that what the Promise.all return is an empty list, otherwise the console would have logged at least something ^^

Ensure the **items** object is an *iterable* object so that [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) will not throw an exception

Let's say we test this using [adonis cli repl](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/database-basics#_what_is_repl) inside your adonis project root so that you can test your application models and also to be sure that your issue does not come from adonis

```
#!/bin/bash
cd <your adonis project root folder>
adonis repl

# stupid test with a fake iterable object
const MAX_ITEMS = 5
const items = []

for (let i = 0; i < MAX_ITEMS; ++i) {
    items.push(i % 2 === 0? i / 2: i * 3 + 1)
}

// let items = []

await Promise.all(items.map(async (item) => { 
    console.log(item)
    return item % 2 === 0 ? item / 2: item * 3 + 1
}))
```

Now the console would have logged this

```
0
4
1
10
2
```

And the result of the Promise.all call would have given this

```
[ 0, 2, 4, 5, 1 ]
```

If you use Promise.all without an iterable object you would see some errors (let you test in using adonis repl)

```
adonis repl

let itemsAsObject = {}
let itemsAsUndefined = undefined
let itemsAsEmptyList = []

async function testPromise(items) {
    return Promise.all(items.map(async (item) => { 
        console.log(item)
        return await item % 2 === 0 ? item / 2: item * 3 + 1
    }))
}

await testPromise(itemsAsObject) // throws an error
await testPromise(itemsAsUndefined) // throws an error
await testPromise(itemsAsEmptyList) // returns []
```

You could use the same mechanic with your own Lucid Models

Cheers :)